# Ionic 3 App is not run on Android device

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I can't run app on Android device it is not giving any error. Here is the output of terminal;

```
Running app-scripts build: --platform android --target cordova
[13:00:25]  build dev started ...
[13:00:25]  clean started ...
[13:00:25]  clean finished in 24 ms
[13:00:25]  copy started ...
[13:00:25]  deeplinks started ...
[13:00:25]  deeplinks finished in 130 ms
[13:00:25]  transpile started ...
[13:00:31]  transpile finished in 5.76 s
[13:00:31]  preprocess started ...
[13:00:31]  preprocess finished in 1 ms
[13:00:31]  webpack started ...
[13:00:31]  copy finished in 6.35 s
[13:00:41]  webpack finished in 10.48 s
[13:00:41]  sass started ...
Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent this warning.
[13:00:44]  sass finished in 2.45 s
[13:00:44]  postprocess started ...
[13:00:44]  postprocess finished in 19 ms
[13:00:44]  lint started ...
[13:00:44]  build dev finished in 19.37 s
> cordova run android
Android Studio project detected

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\umutg\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk-10
(node:3684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CordovaError: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
(node:3684) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

[OK] Your app has been deployed.
     Did you know you can live-reload changes from your app with --livereload?
```

I think It does not see device, It does not work on another device or emulator. I create new app for trying it's same.

Answer (score 0):

It's about JDK V 10, I uninstalled it and works fine.